# xsim solution environment within exercise environment vs outside exercise environment

Tags: xsim

For previous versions of xsim, it was possible to have the solution environment *within* the exercise environment and the global command `\xsimsetup{solution/print = true}` would print the solutions right after the corresponding exercises (tested with a tex live distribution from 2017). Now (tested with tex live 2021), it only prints the solutions, if the solutions environment is *outside* of the exercise environment. Otherwise, it ignores the command `\xsimsetup{solution/print = true}`.

Are there any workarounds? Or did I miss something in the manual? Thanks.

MWE for solution environment within exercise environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{solution/print = true}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
    %
    QUESTION
%solution within exercise environment
\begin{solution}
    SOLUTION
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I never intended `solution` to work inside `exercise`. That it did in the beginning was by chance... I vaguely remember that there was an issue on https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues about this but wasn't able to find it right now.

Comment: @cgnieder Fair enough; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was never intended for `solution` to work inside `exercise`.
That it did in the beginning was by chance.

In recent updates the exercise environments changed in a way that it's now impossible.